# Formatting Records in Crystal Report 8.5

Tags: crystal-reports-8.5

I want to display 16 students seat no like 4 students in each column. Four seat numbers in descending order and next 4 seat numbers in next column in ascending order like-

1001___1008___1009___1016
1002___1007___1010___1015
1003___1006___1011___1014
1004___1005___1012___1013

Please help me , how to do it in Crystal Report 8.5

I am using VB6 and SQL Server 2014

Comment: I have number of Seat Numbers and want to display only 16 seat numbers in Crystal Report A4 size paper, please help me to sort out.. next 16 seat numbers in another page..next 16 seat numbers in third page and so on...

Comment: Mr. Alec.. Thank you very much... Problem not solved

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a record to your dataset to split the students up into column a and b, then create two group fields. Suppress the first one to hide the second group of students then suppress the second one to hide the first group of students.

Then in the section expert for the second group, select "Underlay section". This will give the appearance of having two columns next to each other.

This can be repeated for as many sections as you need.

[image]